# Impossible to share internet from iPhone 8 to iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, internet-sharing

When trying to share internet from an iPhone 8 (iOS 15.5) to an iPhone 5 (iOS 10) using WiFi, the latter always fails to connect with a `could not connect to the network "iPhone 8"`.

The iPhone 5 clearly sees the network, but invariably fails to connect a dozen times in a row. I have not mistyped the password every single time.

Meanwhile, multiple other devices that aren't even 5 GHz capable have no trouble connecting.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be solved in iOS 16 where it's possible to explicitly turn on a new option to maximize compatibility when sharing internet.

I don't know the nature of the compatibility changes.